# Type based Header converter for Feign clients

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, feign, openfeign

in our spring boot project we are using `feign core` library and in code below you can see how looks generated method of one of our client. `CustomSecurityContext` is basic data class with security attributes. Is possible create some type based header converter which take header of specific type and convert it? For instance in that case we need serialize `CustomSecurityContext` into json, for instance with jackson.

```
    @Headers("X-SecurityContext: { xSecurityContext }")
    @RequestLine("GET /card/detail")
    fun getUserCardDetail(Param("xSecurityContext") xSecurityContext: CustomSecurityContext): CardDetailResponse
```

I found out that there exists Expanders in feign which should be used inside `@Param` annotation in client definition, unfortunatelly I am not able manipulate with that code because it is generated.

Thank you.